# A-Frame camera vs three.js camera peformance on scene with large number of elements

Tags: three.js, aframe

The following code pen stress tests 3 scenarios: https://codepen.io/ubermario/pen/QqWQPa

```
...
    this.el.setObject3D(objName, cubeObj);  //register to A-Frame; accessible with this.el.getObject3D(objName)
...
```

1. Scrolling through as many as 60,000 cubes on a scene using the default camera with WASD control.  Cubes were generated with the .setObject3D method which registers the dynamically generated elements to A-Frame.
2. Scrolling through as many as 60,000 cubes on a scene using the default camera with WASD control.  Cubes were generated with the three.js object3D.add method which does not register the dynamically generated elements to A-Frame.
3. Scrolling through as many as 60,000 cubes on a scene using a three.js orbital control camera.  Cubes were generated with the three.js object3D.add method.  This scenario is similar to scenario #2.

**Question**:  While all 3 scenarios load very quickly. Scenario #3 always performs consistently well when scrolling.  Scenario #1 and #2 sometimes have 'jagged' image refresh.

Any suggestions to achieve the performance of scenario #3 with scenario #1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is that in example #3, OrbitControls manages the `render()` loop. As a result, it only decides to render when the scrollwheel is actually moving, and can keep things smoother. You can test this out by adding `console.log('render')` in the render function, and seeing that it only prints when you scroll.

That strategy doesn't help in VR, where you need to re-render at 90 FPS no matter what (because the HMD is always moving). So unfortunately, there's no way to do the same thing in A-Frame.

What you could do, if rendering lots of similar objects is a goal, would be  [instancing](https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-instancing) or [merging geometry](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/geometry.html#mergeto) to reduce draw calls.